# How to find the top element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Given an element on a page, I want to find the element at the very top of this element.  So if I had a `<div id="A">` with `<img id="B">` on top if it, with `<div id="C">` on top of the image, with `<img id="D">` on top of the div, then from div#A I could find that the top element was img#D.

Is there a simple way to do  this with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: At the very top of each element will be `<html>`

Comment: Do you mean "on top" as in how the elements are positioned with CSS (if they overlap), or as in position within the DOM structure?

Comment: I mean "on top" as the browser places them.  So the first element in the HTML would be on the bottom and last element in the HTML would be on top.

Comment: So starting from div A you want to find its last sibling?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('#A').parent().child('first');
```

The .parent() will get the container of #A and .child('first') will get the first child of that element.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id-name of the top element you could use:

```
$("#d").parents("#a");
```

This affects every parent of #d with id="a". For clarity, check out [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q8CL/).

Ther is also another way of using parents if you don't know the ID, but you know the element the top DIV is placed in.

For example:

```
<body>
    <div id="a">
        This is A
        <div id="b>">
            This is B
            <div id="c">
                This is C
                <div id="d">
                    Thid is D
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then you could use `.map()` to search through the array and see whether the `tagName` is 'BODY' or not, and if so, get the position in the array - 1 and you have the array number correpsonding to the element with ID="a".

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Q8CL/2/) will clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to distill the problem I was having into something simple, but I didn't capture the essence of the problem in this question, and now we're going off track, so I don't think I can save the question.  I apologize.  I've recasted the question at

[Filtering multiple drop handler interrupts for stacked elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652094/filtering-multiple-drop-handler-interrupts-for-stacked-elements)

Hopefully you'll pop over there and take a look.

Thank you all for looking at the above question.