# Filtering multiple drop handler interrupts for stacked elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have some `<div>` elements set up with droppable to receive thumbnail images that are dropped on them, dragged from a gallery. `<img>` elements are also set up to accept these thumbnails, so I could have an image on top of an image.  The drop handlers recover the image from the thumbnail and  and append it to the body.

A problem occurs when there are multiple divs and imgs stacked on top of each other and a thumb gets dropped on the stack. The drop handler for each of these stacked elements gets called when the thumb is dropped and wants to process the thumb into an image and append it to the body.  The result is multiple copies of the same image.

How can I process the thumbnail drop just one time for all the interrupts that the drop generates so I end up with just a single image?

Thanks

Comment: One approach is to have each element contain a self-described z-order (e.g. `data-z-order`), queue up all of your drops, order by z-order, then pick the highest one in your handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a small proof of concept on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9M8gP/21/).  A quick breakdown:

`processDroppedElement` searches the list of dropped elements and selects the appropriate element.  You can obviously customize the selection criteria.  After processing the event, it resets state variables appropriately.

```
var processDroppedElement = function() {

    $("p").html("");

    var targetElement = null;
    var targetZ = -1;

    for (var i in droppedElements) {
        var element = droppedElements[i];
        var zOrder = $( element ).data("zOrder");
        if (zOrder && zOrder > targetZ) {
            targetElement = element;
        }            
    }

    if (targetElement) {
         $( targetElement )
              .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
              .find( "p" )
                .html( "Dropped!" );
        droppedElement = null;
    }

    $("#draggable").css({
        'left': $("#draggable").data('originalLeft'),
        'top': $("#draggable").data('origionalTop')
    });

    droppedElements = [];
};
```

This section of code defines basic variables used to manage dropped elements and firing the `processDroppedElement` function.

```
var droppedTimer;
var droppedElements = [];

var queueDroppedElement = function(element) {
    droppedElements.push(element);
}
```

The drop function simply queues elements and creates a timeout to launch the processing logic.  It pre-clears any existing timeouts to ensure the function is only run once.  This is a bit of a hack, but functional

```
$( ".droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {

      var myZorder = $( this ).data("zOrder");
      console.log("zOrder: " + myZorder);

      queueDroppedElement(this);

      clearTimeout(droppedTimer);
      droppedTimer = setTimeout(processDroppedElement, 50);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I  gave you the points for thinking about this with me. I think there may be a simpler way, though.

When the thumb is dropped on the stack, the elements receiving the thumb fire the drop handler in the order the element occurs in the stack, from bottom up. So the top element fires the handler last. So we just have to wait until all the elements in the stack fire and then take the last one:

```
function box_drop(e,ui) {

    g.drop_last_e = e;
    g.drop_last_ui = ui;
    if(g.th) clearTimeout(g.th);      // if timer is running, cancel it
    g.th = setTimeout(box_drop_last, 10); // and start a new 10ms wait

}

function box_drop_last() {  
    // it's been 10ms since last drop: we surely must be done   
    e  = g.drop_last_e; 
    ui = g.drop_last_ui;

      // add image on top of this e/ui
}
```

In my case, though, there could also be an image in the stack, so the image drop handler is running concurrently.  I think I need to do the same thing in this handler. At the end of 10ms both handlers will have handled everything in the stack so I can check the z-index of the last element each handler saw and place the dropped thumb on top of that.

Please let me know if you have any additional thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent this behaviour (at least in Firefox).

After doing this only the highest element in the stack receives the event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation